# systemd not detected, dockerd daemon needs to be started manually

Tags: systemd, users, docker, services, daemon

I am trying to install Docker daemon as non root user, following this guide: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

First, I removed the existing rootful docker daemon.

Then I created a user called `docker-user` and made it a member of `docker` group

Then I switched to shell for that docker-user like so:

```
sudo -iu docker-user
```

And ran the rootless docker installation script given at the link above.

Script output:

```
docker-user@ubuntu:~$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
# Installing stable version 19.03.8
# Existing rootless Docker detected at /home/docker-user/bin/dockerd
# systemd not detected, dockerd daemon needs to be started manually

/home/docker-user/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental --storage-driver vfs

# Docker binaries are installed in /home/docker-user/bin
# Make sure the following environment variables are set (or add them to ~/.bashrc):

export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/docker-1003/docker.sock
```

Looking at the script, the line `systemd not detected, dockerd daemon needs to be started manually` is output if `systemctl --user daemon-reload` falis

The output of `systemctl --user daemon-reload` is

```
docker-user@ubuntu:~$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I don't want to start docker manually, it should run as a service like the usual docker installation. As per the guide, I should be able to run it as a service. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `Failed to connect to bus` message is a bit misleading - the acutal problem is missing `root` permissions to run `daemon-reload`.

Comment: But this user should not need root permission. It is not clear which user this command should be run as. I was assuming it is the non-root user.

Comment: What distro are you setting this up on?

Comment: Tried with Ubuntu 18.04 and then with a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM

Comment: Hello @Dojo, sorry I have the same kind of issue with this. How did you remove the existing rootful docker daemon? Please advice.

Comment: I don't remember the exact packages I removed but based on this article: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ 
This should this should be the exhaustive list of all docker components: 
`sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`
After that, for installation of rootless docker, as mentioned in the accepted answer, you should ssh into the system as the non-root user you want to run docker as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to login via ssh as the non-root user and then run the script.

<del>`sudo -iu docker-user`</del>

`ssh docker-user@hostname`

(`docker-user` is an example, use any non root user that exists on the target system)

There is no need for this user to be member of the docker group.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You will either need to log in with `pam_systemd` or enable user lingering for your user, then you can troubleshoot `systemctl --user`.

### To log in with `pam_systemd` ([source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#errors-when-starting-the-docker-daemon))

Try one of the following methods:

- Log in through the graphic console
- `ssh <user>@localhost`
- `machinectl shell <user>@`

After logging in, you should see your session with `loginctl list-sessions`. If you do, proceed to "Troubleshooting `systemctl --user`".

Otherwise, if none of the above methods work, instead try to enable user lingering as documented below.

### To enable user lingering (with `loginctl`)

Check if the user is already lingering

`ls /var/lib/systemd/linger` ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/849280/774940))

If you see your user here, proceed to "Troubleshooting `systemctl --user`".

Otherwise, enable user lingering with `loginctl enable-linger <user>`. Note that you may omit the `<user>` argument to use the current user.

Then, you should see your user with `ls /var/lib/systemd/linger`.

### Troubleshooting `systemctl --user`

Now that you know your user is either active with `pam_systemd` or is lingering, you may try to connect to `systemd`:

Run `systemctl --user`

If this command runs without errors, then `systemd` should be ready to go to install rootless docker.

If this prints `Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)` then set `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to the proper value (usually `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID`)

Then run `systemctl --user`

If this command runs without errors, then `systemd` should be ready to go to install rootless docker.

If this prints `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`, then you probably did not log in with `pam_systemd` or did not enable user lingering.

Comment: Great answer! What could be the reason that XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set?

Comment: Thanks! I think I had that issue when switching users with the `su` command.  

I think I originally stumbled upon this issue when I was attempting to automate the installation of rootless docker on a remote machine by writing a script which logs in via `ssh`, switches to a different user with `su`, and runs the rootless install script. This resulted in the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` not being set up at all. This was tricky to debug because I barely knew what `systemd` was at the time, and the error message I was getting from the install script was not helpful at all!