# rootless docker systemctl daemon errors

Tags: docker, services, daemon, systemctl

I am trying to run docker on rootless user, but I can't seem to start daemon in any way using `systemctl`.

I use Debian 11. To log into the user with root privileges I use key pair and any login to other accounts other than through the privileged user is disabled.

After following tutorial for setting up rootless docker at https://statswork.wiki/engine/security/rootless/ I got this output:

```
[INFO] systemd not detected, dockerd-rootless.sh needs to be started manually:

PATH=/home/docker-user/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH dockerd-rootless.sh

[INFO] Creating CLI context "rootless"
Successfully created context "rootless"

[INFO] Make sure the following environment variables are set (or add them to ~/.bashrc):

# WARNING: systemd not found. You have to remove XDG_RUNTIME_DIR manually on every logout.
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/docker-user/.docker/run
export PATH=/home/docker-user/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///home/docker-user/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

I set the variables as such and got the following error upon running systemctl --user

`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

I found this thread: [systemd not detected, dockerd daemon needs to be started manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587674/systemd-not-detected-dockerd-daemon-needs-to-be-started-manually) , after which I successfully enabled lingering for the user and set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID`.

`systemctl --user` worked as it was supposed to, but suddenly the problem was running `systemctl --user start docker`:

`Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.`

I suspect this is a problem because the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable is not set as `/home/docker-user/.docker/run`. Alas, I cannot set it as such, because `systemctl --user` will not work at all, so I am stuck here. I am unable to log in to user with `pam_systemd` because as I mentioned above, ssh login to other users is not permitted. I tried reinstalling rootless docker, but the same errors occur.

Is there any way to enable docker service properly?