# Docker rootless daemon not starting

Tags: systemd, rhel, docker, d-bus

I installed docker rootless with `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install` to rhel 7.9. The info of the output is below.

`[INFO] systemd not detected, dockerd-rootless.sh needs to be started manually:`

When I try to start the service with `systemctl --user start docker` as it is described in the documentation, it failed with error `Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory`.
I read some of the posts in here and to debug the situation, I enabled lingering of the mentioned user. I can see the file at the path `ll /var/lib/systemd/linger`. After that, when I run `systemctl --user` command, again the Failed Dbus connection error occurs.
I can list my user after enabling linger with the `loginctl list-users`, but when I run `ps -fu dockeruser`, the output didn't show `/usr/lib/systemd --user` as it suppose to be. The output is below.

```
ps -fu dockeruser
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
dockeru+  45222  45220  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 sshd: dockeruser@pts/0
dockeru+  45225  45222  0 10:58 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
dockeru+  45254  45223  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 sshd: dockeruser@notty
dockeru+  45255  45254  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
dockeru+  47264  45222  0 11:10 ?        00:00:00 bash -c while [ -d /proc/$PPID ]; do sleep 1;head -v -n 8 /proc/meminfo; head -v -n 2 /proc/s
dockeru+  50009  47264  0 11:18 ?        00:00:00 sleep 1
dockeru+  50010  45225  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -fu dockeruser
```

I use ssh to login to the server. My dockeruser's bashrc is set as docker installation required.

```
#User specific aliases and functions
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/dockeruser/.docker/run
export PATH=/bin:$PATH
# Some applications may require the following environment variable too:
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///home/dockeruser/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

Also in documentation it is referred that `The systemd unit file is installed as ~/.config/systemd/user/docker.service.` When I checked that file, I found out that it is missing. Maybe the setuptool is problematic or sth?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587674/systemd-not-detected-dockerd-daemon-needs-to-be-started-manually) help?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I followed that post before writing my own but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution: use rhel 8.